# Does the integral of $(\ln x) / (e^x+1)$ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration

I ran into this integral question:

$$\int_{ 2 }^{ \infty } \frac{\ln x } { e ^ { x } + 1 } d x$$

Does it converge or diverge?

Comment: Sara, please use MathJax (LaTeX notation) to format math, or let other people edit the question for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\ln x < x$ and $e^x > x^3$, for sufficiently large $x$, 
$$\frac {\ln x}{e^x+1} < \frac x {x^3}$$

$$ \int_a^\infty \frac {\ln x}{e^x+1} \text d x< \int_a^\infty \frac x {x^3} \text d x$$
Since the right-side integral converges, and all are positive, so does the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$\lim_{x\to \infty }\left|\frac{x^2\ln(x)}{e^x+1}\right|=0,$$
then
$$\frac{\ln(x)}{e^x+1}=o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right),$$
at $+\infty $.

In particular, $$\left|\frac{\ln(x)}{e^x+1}\right|\leq \frac{1}{x^2},$$
when $x$ is big enough.